# How to make the Reed Richards's portal?

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes, animation-nodes

[image: My nodes]I was watching the Reed Richards portal scene from the Multiverse of Madness movie and I wonder how to make it inside Blender, do you have any thoughts? I tried using a voronoi texture and a noise texture connected to the displacement to make the patterns but I don't know how where to connect the emission and make the object to be more transparent.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Portal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a mix between an *Emission* node and a *Transparent*, use a *Noise Texture* as factor. Also use a *MixRGB* to mix a *Noise* or a *Musgrave* with the *Texture Coordinate* in order to perturbate the texture. For the bright effect in the middle you could use a *Gradient* texture in *Spherical* mode. Add a *Point* light and some *Bloom* if you're in Eevee:

[image]

[image]

Comment: WOAH! That's amazing!! you archieved the look I was searching for, thanks a lot

Comment: Do I need to activate something in EEVEE? my looks with a flat blue color

Comment: @AlexisRivera You could always switch on bloom and increase the intensity :)

Comment: Yes, Bloom is in the Render panel, in Eevee. No Bloom in Cycles, if you want the same kind of effect you need to use the Compositor, the Glare effect for example

Comment: I used glare in the compositor on cycles thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd take a procedural approach:

First, take a gradient texture node, and set it to *Quadratic Sphere* with a colour ramp to get the bright spot of the portal opening in the middle. Then, add a Musgrave texture node and combine it with the gradient with a MixRGB Node set to *Overlay*. Then connect this into .....

Long story short, do this:[image][image]